# In angular lazy loading component mat datepicker not closing after it opens

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, angular-material-datetimepicker

I am using angular and angular material v15. In lazy load component I am using material date picker. When I am going select date from it after selecting date it is not closing.
I imported all the necessary modules in shared module file.
The date picker was working properly in not lazily loaded component.

I tried to import necessary all the material modules in the lazily loaded module.but it seems not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Bsg.png)` <section  *ngIf="enableDob">

```
            <div id="Heading" class="margin-content input-box">
               <input class="form-control" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="dob" (ngModelChange)="dobCheck(oEligibility.dob)" id="dob" placeholder=" " type="text" />                 
               <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
               <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
               <label for="dob" class="form-label">date of birth</label>
            </div>
          </section>`
```

also UI showing this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zd22.png)

Comment: Hi Amii, could you please share the minimum reproducible code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.